# Export FBX while keeping Collections Hierarchy

Tags: scripting, export, unity, .fbx, collections

I am looking for a way to transfer the hierarchy of the collections from Blender to Unity. In other programs, like Cinema 4D, this works without any problems.

Is it possible to export a fbx-file with the hierarchy of the collections?

Currently I use a script that translates the structure into a new hierarchy.

```
import bpy

sCollection = bpy.context.collection

def parentCol(_colParent, _objParent):
    for col in _colParent.children:
        newObj = bpy.data.objects.new("empty", None)
        bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(newObj)
        newObj.name = col.name
        newObj.parent = _objParent
    
        if len(col.objects) > 0:
            objs = col.objects
            for obj in objs:
                obj.parent = newObj
        else:
            parentCol(col, newObj)
                
root = bpy.data.objects.new("empty", None)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(root)
root.name = sCollection.name

parentCol(sCollection, root)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to understand if transforming parenting informations into collections should lead to possibility to batch export with Blender Function for FBX.
While I'm not skilled with coding into blender, I'd love to resolve this issue to correctly export Groups and parents/children into Unreal Engine:

My idea:

My case example:

Object01
Object02
…

Need to Create Collection automatically and set the relative object inside:

Collection01\Object01_grp (and inherited objects)
Collection02\Object02_grp (and inherited objects)
…

Hope it could be possible…

Comment: This kind of response fits forums such as BlenderArtists. On BS Exchange answers need to be definite.

Answer (score 0):

i have similiar issue where i have a lot of assets in one file and some assets have obj hierarchy that include child meshes. i dont want each mesh exported individually so i modified the `batch_export` template to skip child objects and include any children for a given obj while exporting. i'm using glb format for export but the script can easily be modified for fbx by changing the export to from `bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(...)` to `bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=fn + ".glb", use_selection=True)`.

**tested in blender 4.0.2**

````
# exports each selected object into its own file

import bpy
import os


def set_object_selection(obj, selected):
    obj.select_set(selected)
    for child in obj.children:
        set_object_selection(child, selected)


# export to blend file location
basedir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)

if not basedir:
    raise Exception("Blend file is not saved")

view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer

obj_active = view_layer.objects.active
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for obj in selection:
    
    # skip exporting child objs
    if obj.parent:
        print("skipping:", obj)
        continue
    
    set_object_selection(obj, True)

    # some exporters only use the active object
    view_layer.objects.active = obj

    name = bpy.path.clean_name(obj.name)
    fn = os.path.join(basedir, "export", name)

    # export as gltf/glb, see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf
    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath=fn + ".glb", 
        export_format='GLB',
        export_materials='PLACEHOLDER',
        use_selection=True)
    
    set_object_selection(obj, False)

    print("written:", fn)


view_layer.objects.active = obj_active

for obj in selection:
    obj.select_set(True)
```
````